# Class 'Zend\ZendPdf\PdfDocument' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

IN MY CONTROLLER:

```
use ZendPdf\PdfDocument;
public function monthlyReportPdfAction(){
    $pdf = new PdfDocument();
    $pdf->pages[0] = new Page( Page::SIZE_A4 );$pdf->pages[0]->setFont( Font::fontWithName( Font::FONT_HELVETICA ), 24 );$pdf->pages[0]->drawText( 'Hello world!', 240, 400 );
    $pdf->save( 'example.pdf' );
}
```

MY zendpdf in vendor
I have created one .phtml and one href in index,,

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use ZendPdf Stand alone you can check previous answer:
[Zend PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717024/where-to-get-and-how-to-use-zend-pdf-standalone)

You may also want to check ZF2 documentation for The Standard Autoloader which give detailed information about namespaces.
[ZF2 Standard Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html)

Comment: I updated my composer again???? now my issue cleared but I am getting empty screen when I click my pdf hyperlink??????give some examples

Answer (score 0):

```
use ZendPdf\Font as Font;
use ZendPdf\Page as Page;
use ZendPdf\PdfDocument as PdfDocument;
```

In class:

```
 public function exportpdfAction()
    {
        $pdf = new PdfDocument();

        $pdf->pages[0] = new Page( Page::SIZE_A4 );
        $pdf->pages[0]->setFont( Font::fontWithName( Font::FONT_HELVETICA ), 24 );
        $pdf->pages[0]->drawText( 'Hello world!', 240, 400 );
        $pdf->save();

        return new ViewModel();
    }
```

In composer.json

```
"zendframework/zendpdf": "*"
```