# Replacement for Zend_pdf to get meta details

Tags: php, zend-pdf

In previous versions of the Zend framework I would do the following:

```
Zend_Pdf::load('/path/to/pdf.pdf');
$metaAuthor     = $pdf->properties['Author'];
$metaTitle     = $pdf->properties['Title'];
$metaSubject    = $pdf->properties['Subject'];
$metaKeywords   = $pdf->properties['Keywords'];
$metaProducer   = $pdf->properties['Producer'];
```

It seems that Zend has eliminated Zend_pdf from the framework sometime after version 1.9.

Is there another way to get the same details out of a .pdf file with something other than an old version of the Zend framework?  (I'm running PHP 5.4 at this point on RedHat if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

There is a standalone version of `ZendPdf` that you could use. It can be found here:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf

I mention it because it may be viable solution for you (ie. you get to use what is essentially the old `Zend_Pdf` but without including the entire framework and with some improvements, like namespaces).

As of two years ago, there was a little bit of trickery required to get it working. I don't know if this advice still applies, but you can read about it here:

[Where to get and how to use zend_pdf standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717024/where-to-get-and-how-to-use-zend-pdf-standalone/14721150#14721150)

I have switched to `TCPDF`, but I don't think you can extract document properties with it.